# Wordpress: the footer.php can not find the content that shows in the web

Tags: wordpress

This is the code in the footer.php

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footermain">
    <a class="BottomLogo" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"></a>
    <div class="footerlinkcode">
        <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('BanLier_footerlinkcode')); ?></br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php do_action( 'BanLier_footerinfo' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the corresponding image is here, http://ringinter.gotoip55.com/
The question is that i want to edit the "ThemesBy:大板栗", but in the footer.php doc, i can not find the relative text, so please tell me how can i do, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your themes functions.php file.

you should be looking for

```
add_action( 'BanLier_footerinfo', 'XXX' );
```

'XXX' is the function that should contain the "ThemesBy:大板栗" text.